# Problems building Rust service containers from Docker scratch image

Tags: docker, rust

I have a Rust binary that I want to run in a container. It works fine when I use a `ubuntu` or even `gcr.io/distroless/cc` as the base image, but when I tried running from the `scratch` image, I ran into some problems. This is obviously because some files are expected to be on the filesystem that aren't there. I was able to work out how to get the CA root certificates installed, but now I get a different error that seems to happen when the binary tries to do a DNS lookup.

My Dockerfile looks mostly like this (I trimmed off some build optimizations):

```dockerfile
FROM rust:latest as cargo-build

WORKDIR /build
ENV RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+crt-static"

COPY aggregator/ ./

RUN cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

#####################################

FROM alpine:3.6 as ca-certificates
RUN apk add -U --no-cache ca-certificates

#####################################

FROM scratch

COPY --from=cargo-build /build/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/aggregator /entrypoint
COPY --from=ca-certificates /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint" ]
```

The error I get when running (from the Rust binary) is:

```
Error: Failed to load job description from S3

Caused by:
    0: io error: error trying to connect: dns error: Device or resource busy (os error 16)
    1: io error: error trying to connect: dns error: Device or resource busy (os error 16)
    2: error trying to connect: dns error: Device or resource busy (os error 16)
    3: dns error: Device or resource busy (os error 16)
    4: Device or resource busy (os error 16)
```

I Googled the error and was able to find another Rust/Docker project with the same error, but they "fixed" the problem by switching from `scratch` to `gcr.io/distroless/cc` as the base image, and I would like to avoid that by understanding what the problem is.

Looking at the file-system, it seems to have a minimal network configuration, but I might be wrong.

```
.
├── dev
│   ├── console
│   ├── pts
│   └── shm
├── entrypoint
├── etc
│   ├── hostname
│   ├── hosts
│   ├── mtab -> /proc/mounts
│   ├── resolv.conf
│   └── ssl
│       └── certs
│           └── ca-certificates.crt
├── proc
└── sys
```

Like I wrote, this works fine with other base images, so what am I missing to get a networked Rust binary to run from "scratch"?

Comment: Don't you need to compile your Rust program with an Alpine image since you're using Alpine to supply the other components? I wouldn't think they would be compatible.

Comment: Nope, it's just a file that one of the dependencies looks for.
Rust statically compiles libc and openssl into the binary, but it doesn't include the files that are expected by those libraries to be present in the filesystem, generally in "/etc".I would have thought that all libc needed for DNS was resolv.conf, but that doesn't seem to be the case ...

Comment: You are building with the x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu which still needs to link glibc among others. have you tried building with the musl target to get a completely static binary?

Comment: No, but if I understand correctly, `RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+crt-static"` does make my app completely static. At least, running `ldd` on it tells me it's not a dynamically linked binary, and lists no dependecies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit this same problem. The issue is likely caused by something in your code trying to call the [`getaddrinfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) system function, which won't work unless some additional shared libraries are present on your system.

For me, the culprit was Hyper, being used by Reqwest. Hyper uses `getaddrinfo` by default to resolve DNS names.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Copy the necessary libraries into your image. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68409203/7099148) suggests what you need to copy, but I haven't tried it.
2. Make sure you're resolving hostnames entirely in rust code.

For the second option, you can use [trust_dns_resolver](https://docs.rs/trust-dns-resolver/latest/trust_dns_resolver/) library as an alternative to `getaddrinfo`. If you're using Reqwest (as I was), you can do this easily by enabling the [`trust-dns`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.10/reqwest/#optional-features) feature on the `reqwest` crate.

If you're using Hyper directly, <s>it looks like it's a bit more tricky. You need to create an implementation of [`Service`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.19/hyper/service/trait.Service.html)`<`[`dns::Name`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.19/hyper/client/connect/dns/struct.Name.html)`>` to use as an alternative to Hyper's default [`GaiResolver`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.19/hyper/client/connect/dns/struct.GaiResolver.html). To get started, you can see (or copy) how Reqwest does it [here](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/master/src/dns.rs).</s> **Update:** Looks like the [hyper-trust-dns](https://docs.rs/crate/hyper-trust-dns/latest) crate is what you want in this scenario.

**Note:** If you're using TLS/HTTPS you may bump into a similar problem with your program trying to use Openssl. You can similarly move TLS stuff "in-house" using [rustls](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.20.6/rustls/). For Reqwest, you can do that with the [`rustls-tls`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.10/reqwest/#optional-features) feature flag along with `default-features = false`. You could also see how you get on with [`native-tls-vendored`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.10/reqwest/#optional-features) instead.